# What is _mce_href?

Tags: html, tinymce, anchor, href

I was looking at some code on a website and I saw the following code for a link:

```
<a href="#" _mce_href="#">Link Text</a>
```

What is `_mce_href`?

Is there a purpose for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a valid HTML attribute, it was kind of bug in older versions of Tiny MCE editor, though, using [`data-`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) prefix before that attribute can make that custom attribute valid as of HTML5.

[Some Reference](http://forums.modx.com/thread/?thread=46081)

Answer (score 1):

This attribute was used in tiny mce. Most of the time developers creates its own attribute(s) to process the tags or data in user define attributes, you can also see in the jquery plugins at run time it add styling or add attributes, you can also create your own attributes, its not a big deal. Well Its not a valid HTML attribute.